# android wear watch face hands

Tags: android, wear-os

It's the first time doing a watch face for android wear so i still don't know lots of things but i am trying. So i am using the android wear watch face api and i set the background i wanted but i am having troubles with the watch hands. All the examples found were with the watch hands done with the paint command, I want to use a png file as a hand. I know how to load the image, but i don't know how to make it rotate. when using paint, it's easy

```
float minX = (float) Math.sin(minRot) * minLength;
        float minY = (float) -Math.cos(minRot) * minLength;
        canvas.drawLine(centerX, centerY, centerX + minX, centerY + minY, mHandPaint);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to draw the hand at the correct angle use [`Canvas.rotate(float)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate(float)) (and ['Canvas.restore()'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#restore())). This is a far easier approach.

Calculate the rotation from the time (assuming hour is from 0 to 11 and minutes is from 0 to 59, a simplified approach would be hour * 60 + minutes), rotate by that value, draw your hour hand as if the time would be at noon (or midnight). After that calculate the rotation for the minute hand using (minute * 60 + seconds) and draw the minutes as if it was noon (or midnight).

Comment: i forgot to mark this problem as solved. i loaded the images for the watch hands in a bitmap, i created a scaledbitmap and assigned a matrix. and using matrix.setRotate and matrix.postTranslate i rotated the hands with a point of rotation set by me and translated it to spin in a certain place on the watch